# Jacobian matrix of summation function

Tags: matrices, summation

So let's say I have a function like this

$(\mu_{ij})_{i,j=1,...,t;i+j>t}\longmapsto \sum_{i,j;i+j>t}  \mu_{ij}$

and I need to find the Jacobian matrix of that function. I tried to calculate it and I found a $1 \times t(t+1)/2$ matrix with 1 as their elements. I'm not too sure of this, please help me. Thank you.

Comment: yes thats right

Comment: Can you post the matrix you found so far? The dimensions sound more or less correct